# How do i make a inset with rounded shape?

Tags: modeling

i was thinking about trying to make a model of the bottle in the picture i attach. I have right now just added a block and used the knife tool to select the area in question.
I think i can handle to form the shape of the bottle, but the selected area is kind of a inset but rounded into the shape of the bottle. So my question is how to do this. I tried with the knife tool but the result was not very good, i allso had a idea of using the boolean tool, but i guess its not more easy to create that shape as a stand alone object.

I would be very glad if some one knows a good way to fix it.
[image]

Comment: Sculpt can help to get the perfect shape, to later retopologize it, too.

Comment: Yeah i think maybe sculpt is the best way, it needs allot of faces but i guess i cant make such model without allot of faces.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can sculpt it, but you can also just mesh model it...

[image]

The edge requires a loop that you can bevel depending on how sharp you want the edge. The challenge is smoothing out the geometry at the pinch...

[image]

Also just added a mirror modifier and of course the sub-division...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

probably easiest to create flattened tube mesh and use knife to follow the shapes, and proportional editing for the indents
(select some segments pull them inwards).
also have some side pictures so you know how deep you should go.

or use Lidar 3d laser scanning, or some app that stitches a 3d model from photo's.

Comment: Yeah maybe the easiest way, i just trying to learn blender a bit more, so this is not a model i seriously want to make, and was wondering if i missed something and maybe there is a better way of fixing this. Problem with the knife is that it dont looks to good with the subdivide modifier, well maybe if i divide it allot.